# Codenamone One Online Build Failure

Tags: codenameone

We added new features to our data collection mobile application after two -three months of inactivity, only for the build to keep failing.
This is the stack trace

```
ll-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.
This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.
However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.
If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.
If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
1 error; aborting
:transformClassesWithDexForRelease FAILED
:transformClassesWithDexForRelease (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 11.045 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --verbose --force-jumbo --num-threads=4 --output /tmp/build8570106392456281219xxx/Application/build/intermediates/transforms/dex/release/0 --min-sdk-version 15 /tmp/build8570106392456281219xxx/Application/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/release/0.jar}
```

Comment: Trace below https://s3.amazonaws.com/codenameone-build-response/7d5b84df-f0d9-4463-94b4-9728e80740cf-1528729945510-error.txt

Comment: I'll need to know which cn1libs you used and what you included in the app to help further

Answer (score 0):

You or one of the cn1libs you are using included a `javax.xml` package as part of the code. We [migrated to build target 27](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/android-build-target-27-migration.html) over the weekend and I'm guessing that Google made checks for this sort of problem more rigid.

I see a lot of keep statements in your build hints so I'm guessing this was done intentionally.

Comment: I actually included **Mozilla Rhino** as a native library that makes use of `javax.xml.namespace.QName`. That's a very important part of our application, hence the reason we added the ` -dontwarn javax.xml.namespace.** ` keep statement.  Is there a way to instruct codename build server to use build target 26?

Comment: The previous build target was 23 not 26. I doubt 26 will fare any better now and Google will block API's lower than 26 in August. `javax.xml.namespace` already exists in the Android native API so why do you need to include it again? I think you should be able to just remove that library

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, removing the library is not possible because its the Rhino Library that powers our javascript runtime execution, it's more powerful than the native javascript runtime.

Comment: The library is several separate jars. You don't need to remove rhino you need to remove the XML parser that's a separate part of rhino. If you have one big jar you can just edit it in a zip tool and remove the `java.xml` packages it should still compile.